# What's the most basic yet interesting Algebraic Geometry result regarding this polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $f(x,y,z) = x^a + y^b - z^c$, where $a,b,c \gt 0$.  What is the most basic yet interesting result about this polynomial from Algebraic Geometry?

Comment: I'm curious as to the motivation? :)

Comment: Motivation is the Beal conjecture.  I'm in the process of learning Alg. Geom, but still not seeing applications to this problem yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in the paper [Faltings plus epsilon, Wiles plus epsilon, and the Generalized Fermat Equation](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/04.Aisenstadt-prize/paper.pdf)  by H. Darmon, which contains a number of interesting results and conjectures about the integer solutions to the equation $f(x,y,z) =0$. For instance, Darmon and Granville conjecture that there are finitely many (primitive) triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ with $x^a+y^b = z^c$ and such that $$1/a+1/b+1/c<1.$$ Moreover, Darmon offers a bounty of

$$300\left(\frac{1}{\frac1a+\frac 1b+\frac1c}-1\right)\:\text{dollars}$$

for any solution not in the list contained in the paper.

(However, please don't search too hard, because Prof. Darmon is my doctoral advisor and I wouldn't want to cause his ruin. Of course, I am kidding: good luck finding any new solutions...)

Comment: Cool! Can you explain why your advisor is so certain these are the only solutions - to someone who knows zero algebraic geometry? The smallest number in each triple is quite small.

Comment: @BennettGardiner Well, if you keep Fermat's Last Theorem in mind, it should not be that surprising that there should be finitely many solutions.

Comment: Really? It seems like there are is another large degree of freedom, namely that the exponents can be different.

Comment: @BennettGardiner There is! But say, if you fix a triple $(a,b,c)$ and you consider all of the equations with exponents $(na, nb, nc)$ for $n>1$, then the analogous statement to Fermat's theorem is that there are no solutions at all to any of those equations. A counter-example should be thought of as an exceptional thing. But, as you say, perhaps there are other solutions. However, it seems very likely to me that there are finitely many in total; the question is then whether they are all listed in the paper...

Comment: That's a good point but it still leaves quite a "lot" of room.

I suppose the first step would be a proof that there is a finite number. Then hunting for solutions, hopefully under some sort of bound.

Comment: @BennettGardiner The freedom that you get by choosing the exponents is quite illusory. Rational points on plane curves of high genus are *extremely* rare (read: inexistent except when they have a special reason to be there). In any case, a proof that the number of solutions is finite is definitely out of reach in the current stage of things. I do encourage you to look for a solution, however!

Comment: Haha. Any hints as to where to look? It's quite a large solution space.

Can you give an example of what you mean by "except when they have a special reason to be there"?

Your explanations are good, thankyou!

Comment: Dear @BennettGardiner: If I knew where to look, I would look myself! There are all kinds of reasons which could cause a curve to have a point. Most of them are pretty difficult to illustrate if you don't know much algebraic geometry. "Modular" curves are probably the best examples. Or, curves which can be parametrized by abelian varieties (an abelian variety is a group, so it always has a least one point, its identity). You are welcome, glad you enjoyed this! :) Regards,

Answer (score 2):

In a similar vein as Bruno's answer, I invite you to take a look at [this paper](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/pss.pdf) of Poonen, Schaefer, and Stoll, in which they *find* all the solutions to $x^2+y^3=z^7$ listed in "Faltings plus epsilon" using algebraic geometry. They also give a nice section summarizing why this case is especially hard and past results on the generalized Fermat equation.